# SQLCMD Mode - ssms 18 vs ssm19 new connection requirements

Tags: sql-server

Given:
Working in SQLCMD Mode in SSMS 18 and SSMS 19

The query below works fine in SSMS 18.

```
:Connect PROD_DB
use [Database1]
select * from people
```

However, in SSM19 this doesn't work any longer.

> Fatal scripting error. Cannot open connection specified in the SQLCMD
> script. A connection was successfully established with the server, but
> then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)

In order to connect to this database, I have to modify the `Connection Properties` in Registered Servers.

I have to check these in properties

1. Encrypt connection
2. Trust server certificate

How can I modify my query to include these new property requirements?

[image]

Comment: You can't. Either use the existing connection settings in SSMS, or connect using `sqlcmd` directly with the `-C` parameter. Or better, get your SQL Server instance a proper certificate.

Comment: You could try `:Connect PROD_DB -C` to trust the server certificate.

Comment: @DanGuzman that worked, thanks if you add as answer I'll mark it! Can you also share some insight, if possible, as to why there's that difference between ssms 18 and ssm19

Comment: @Rod, although the `-C` argument works, the option is undocumented so it's not really an answer. The issue is with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (which newer SSMS uses) where the [certificate is checked by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/encryption-and-certificate-validation?view=sql-server-ver16#changes-in-encryption-and-certificate-validation-behavior) when the server is configured to force encryption.